# Having trouble getting jquery tabledit plugin to work on multiple tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been working on a small project where I display multiple tables for a user on a web page. I would like for the users to be able to edit their tables and have that data update in the database. I'm using the jQuery tabledit plugin to achieve this.

I followed this tutorial [Live editable tables](http://www.phpzag.com/create-live-editable-table-with-jquery-php-and-mysql/) and was able to successfully get this to work for one table.

The problem I'm having is this doesn't seem to be working for all my tables. I can only click into the first displayed table but I need to be able to edit all of them.

I've searched for anybody trying to achieve something similar but couldn't find much.

```php
<?php

// ...

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

?>
<table id="data_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>col1</th>
            <th>col2</th>
            <th>col3</th>
            <th>col4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row ['col1_data']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row ['col2_data']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row ['col3_data']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row ['col4_data']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php 

    }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#data_table').Tabledit({
    deleteButton: false,
    editButton: false,
    columns: {
      identifier: [ 0, 'col1_data' ],
      editable: [ [ 1, 'col2_data' ], [ 2, 'col3_data' ], [ 3, 'col4_data' ] ],
    },
    hideIdentifier: false,
    url: 'includes/liveedit.inc.php',
  })
})
```

I think this may be a problem with each table having the same identifier but I'm not sure. I return each table from the database with a unique identifier but I'm not sure how to use that with the plugin (it seems like I need to).

Sorry if this has an easy solution. I'm pretty new to php and jQuery.

Thanks in advance for any help and please let me know if I'm not being clear enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an **id** and it **must be unique**. Your while statement creates many tables with **the same id**.

Your JS always going to the first table with such id. Change it on **class**. Don't use id if you wanna apply your JS code at once.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.data_table').Tabledit({
        deleteButton: false,
        editButton: false,
        columns: {
            identifier: [0, 'col1_data'],
            editable: [[1, 'col2_data'], [2, 'col3_data'], [3, 'col4_data']]
        },
        hideIdentifier: false,
        url: 'includes/liveedit.inc.php'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-tabledit@1.0.0/jquery.tabledit.min.js"></script> 

                  <table class="data_table">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>col1</th>
                              <th>col2</th>
                              <th>col3</th>
                              <th>col4</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <td>rew</td>
                              <td>ter</td>
                              <td>yrt</td>
                              <td>qwe</td> 
                          </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
                  
                                    <table class="data_table">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>col1</th>
                              <th>col2</th>
                              <th>col3</th>
                              <th>col4</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <td>data_column1</td>
                              <td>dat2a_column1</td>
                              <td>da3ta_column1</td>
                              <td>data_co5lumn1</td> 
                          </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
```

Press ENTER in the snippet for saving the new value

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I changed it to class instead of id and it works perfectly!